# RTABMAP 2D Occupancy Grid showing color

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am driving on a grey track with a green grass surrounding. I have a kinect plugin which I modified to reflect Intel d435 parameters. How can I have the 2D Occupancy Grid reflect the change in the color? I want to be able to create a map file that colors the grey track as the track we can drive on and the green grass as the part we can't drive on

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367041/rtabmap-2d-occupancy-grid-showing-color/) by [sisaha9](https://answers.ros.org/users/63612/sisaha9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2020-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If Grid/3D is true, the `/rtabmap/cloud_map`  point cloud will contain colors. You could recreate an occupancy grid by projecting the cloud on the xy plane and set grey points as empty, and green points as obstacles.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2020-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1